# Importing a tuple to a list from a function

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, range

I'm trying to modify pixels using range in a loop but I can't import the range from size function.

```
    load = bnw.load()
    loadpx = [
        (a),
        (b)
    ]
    bnw.size(loadpx)
    print(loadpx)
    for x in a:
        for y in b:
            new = load[x,y] + 10
            if new > 254:
                new = 254

            bnw = new
```

The output from bnw.size should be the number of pixels the image has ex. (1920,1080). after knowing the size a is inputted to the x and b to y.

the full code withe the first answer returned the same error

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import os
import time
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np  


main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.title("foto epic")
judul = tk.Label(main_window, text="                Editor Instagram epic 2 BnW Edition wkwk                \n\n Silahkan Input foto Dibawah\n\/\n")
judul.pack()

def UploadAction():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print('Selected:', file)
    img = Image.open(file)
    bnw2 = img.convert(mode = "L")
    print(bnw2.size)
    load = bnw2.load()
    r,c = bnw2.size()
    for x in range(r):
        for y in range(c):
            new = load[x,y] + 10
            if new > 254:
                new = 254

            new = bnw2
    arraying = np.asarray(bnw2)
    counting = np.bincount(arraying.flatten(), minlength = 128)
    px_num = np.sum(counting)

    counting = counting/px_num
    sum1 = np.cumsum(counting)
    floorcount = np.floor(255 * sum1).astype(np.uint8)
    donecount = list(arraying.flatten())

    transforming = [floorcount[p] for p in donecount]
    transforming = np.reshape(np.asarray(transforming), arraying.shape)
    done_transform = Image.fromarray(transforming)
    done = tk.Label(main_window, text=" \nFoto Telah di export!\nTerimakasih Sudah Menggunakan Program ini!\n")
    done.pack()
    done_transform.show()
    if os.path.exists('result.jpg'):
        done_transform.save('result_{}.jpg'.format(int(time.time())))
    else:
        done_transform.save('result.jpg')

button = tk.Button(main_window, text='Beautify!', command=UploadAction)
button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

I use Tkinter for UI I don't know if it would affect the original question

the error

```
Selected: D:/Code/Kuliah/Semester 3/citra/yes/DSC_3044.jpg
(4608, 1975) < the resolution if printed
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\Code\Kuliah\Semester 3\citra\yes\Tugas Pengolahan Citra.py", line 22, in UploadAction
    r,c = bnw2.size()
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i edited the answer this should work now:

```
file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print('Selected:', file)
img = Image.open(file)
bnw2 = img.convert(mode = "L")
load = bnw2.load()
r,c = bnw2.size
for x in range(r):
    for y in range(c):
        new = load[x,y] + 10
        if new > 254:
            new = 254

        load[x,y] = new
```

Comment: where in your code is `bnw` defined?

Comment: its on top of 'load', i updated the question, thank you.

Comment: I edited the answer please try it again.

Comment: it still returned with the same error sadly

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: make sure you typed `bnw2.size` not `bnw2.size()`

Comment: the error on my edited post, i did change it accordingly and still same

Comment: how is that possible? can you post your code after edit with the error?

Comment: `load[x,y] = bnw2` should be `load[x,y] = new` as well

Comment: i edited my post with the errors

Comment: your are still using `bnw2.size()` just replace it with `bnw2.size` use it without the parenthesis